# Routing subscriptions in Spring Websocket STOMP with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

I have configured Spring STOMP with ActiveMQ, it works fine.
But, is there any chance to make client's subscription routing?

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

What I want to achieve is two queues for notifications (on frontend) - one for admin users, and one for normal users. Users do not send any messages, only receive ones from server. Let's say that any user can send following subscription request:

```
// app is application destination prefix
client.subscribe('/app/notificator', ...);
```

Server should routes this request to ActiveMQ:

```
/topic/notificator/admin - if logged user is of role admin, or
/topic/notificator/user - if logged user is of role user
```

How to configure Spring to make such routing policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it with controller:

```
@Controller
public class QueueController {

    @SubscribeMapping("/notificator")
    public String getNotificatorQueue(Principal principal) {
        String role = // get role from principal
        return "/topic/notificator/" + role;
    }

}
```

This way I can get url for user subscription, which I'll invoke on "/app/notificator" repsonse.

Comment: Are you using this response as a destination and passing it to the stompclient.subscribe() ? if so, this isn't secure as the client-side code can easily change the destination before subscribing